# MaterialBottomTabs - Fora do limite da tela

Tags: android, react-native, apk, react-navigation, expo

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um app com o Expo e estou usando o React Navigation para realizar as navegações e o MaterialBottomTabs na tela principal. Quanto teste o app no Expo Client do Android funciona perfeitamente, mas quando gero o APK e instalo no dispositivo, o MaterialBottomTabs fica "cortado", ou seja, ele meio que excede os limites da tela.

Segue o print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Expo CLI 3.9.0 environment info:

System:

- OS: Linux 5.0 Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo)
- Shell: 5.5.1 - /usr/bin/zsh

Binaries:

- Node: 12.13.0 - /usr/bin/node
- Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/bin/yarn
- npm: 6.12.0 - /usr/bin/npm

npmPackages:

- expo: ^35.0.0 => 35.0.0
- react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
- react-native:
  https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz =>
  0.59.8
- react-navigation: ^4.0.10 => 4.0.10

npmGlobalPackages:

- expo-cli: 3.9.0

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser isso?

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Posta o código, não tem como saber só com a visão da tela!